# My audio tracks are out of sync

Tags: javascript, html, synchronization

I have 5 audio tracks on my site, I played them onload() function, on localhost they are sync with each other perfect, but on live they are not sync,
Here is my HTML code

```
<body onload="play_sounds();">
    <audio  id="inst" src="newReindeer/inst.mp3" loop preload="auto" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
    <audio  id="ten" src="newReindeer/tenor.mp3" loop preload="auto" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
    <audio  id="child"  src="newReindeer/child.mp3" loop preload="auto" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
    <audio  id="lispy"  src="newReindeer/lispy.mp3" loop preload="auto" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
    <audio  id="soprano"  src="newReindeer/soprano.mp3" loop preload="auto" type="audio/mp3"></audio>

    <div id="pointer_div" onclick="point_it(event)" style = "background-image:url('Visuals/desktop-2160x1920.png');width:2160px;height:1920px;">
    </div>      
</body>
```

and This is my js code

```
var audio1 = document.getElementById('inst');
    var audio2 = document.getElementById('ten');
    var audio3 = document.getElementById('child');
    var audio4 = document.getElementById('lispy');
    var audio5 = document.getElementById('soprano');

    function play_sounds(){         
            audio1.play();
            audio2.play();
            audio3.play();
            audio3.muted=true;
            audio4.play();
            audio4.muted=true;
            audio5.play();
            audio5.muted=true;
    }
```

This working fine on local, please tell me why my tracks are out of sync on live?

Comment: because network lag - you need to determine when they're playable

Comment: when they're playable means???

Comment: to be honest I don't know enough about audio tags to help - however, I do know that they are loaded asynchronously, so, you can't just assume all audio will be ready to play when the body onload fires - if I knew more, I'd have posted an answer

Comment: Ok thanks, Did you know how to play tracks onload in mobile?